# Custom "With" Report Type returning "Without" records

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I discovered today with custom reports that have 'with' relationships that records 'without' related records are being returned.

Custom Report Type:

Accounts with Memberships

When I run this report, if I only pull in fields from the Account object, Accounts without Memberships are showing in the report. These accounts do get listed as unique rows.

As soon as I add a field from the Membership object, then only Account With Memberships show up.

I have not found this to be the case with standard report types.

E.g. Standard report type of Opportunities with Products does not show this behavior. If I run this report type and only add Opportunity Name, then the opportunity name will show multiple times(once per Opp Product) but opportunities without products will not show.

Have others experienced this? Is this known behavior? I have always understood report types to be literal and this can be deceiving if when utilizing a 'With' report if it will actually show 'without' records.

**Steps to recreate:**

1. Create a Custom report type of Object A with Object B
2. Save
3. Create a new report using the newly created report type Only
4. add a field from Object A to your report preview. You will find records 
   returned that do not have related Object B records.

Answer (score 0):

When adding object B to the new custom record type, be sure to mark

**Each "A" record must have at least one related "B" record**

instead of

**"A" records may or may not have related "B" records**

Comment: That is how I have my report defined. My report is set up as **Each "A" record must have at least one related "B" record**

The problem is that when I run the report with only "A" fields that "A" records without "B" records show on the report

Comment: What I gonna say is weird, but happent me sometimes. Check the date you are filtering with. In my case, changing the date filter with value All Time using created date of object A and created date of object B returned different results, one was the expected another wasn´t.